# SpringBoot: Using @RequestParam and @RequestBody together

Tags: spring-boot

It looks like there are a few questions on this topic, but many are now out of date, or are asking reasonably different things.

I am using SpringBoot and the @RestController annotation.

I have a simple use case. I want to send a JSON string to a REST endpoint, that also contains a RequestParameter.

For example, I want to do

```
curl -d '{ "name": "Joe Bloggs" }' http://localhost:8080/test?debug=Y
```

I don't want to send the request parameter in the

I have a method signature that accepts both a request parameter and a request body (it's Kotlin, but I don't think that actually makes any difference here).

```
@PostMapping(value = ["/test"])
fun getGCP(@RequestBody json: String, @RequestParam debug: String) : String
```

I can access the RequestParam fine, but the RequestBody contains more than just  the JSON I have sent through in the body, it contains a merge of the body and the request parameters. In the example above it would output the following for the body binding

```
debug=Y&{"name": "Joe Blogs"}=
```

Is there a way that I can simply get the RequestParameter and RequestBody as separate entities?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the content encoding of the incoming request. Changing the curl command to

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{ "name": "Joe Bloggs" }' http://localhost:8080/test?debug=Y
```

Resulted in my output showing

```
debug=N
json={ "name": "Joe Bloggs" }
```